# Where do I place my web files using Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, filesystems

I'm spinning up a new server using Ubuntu hosted by IBM Softlayer I used CentOS before this. 
I placed my HTML, Javascript or/& PHP files in the folder `/var/www/html`. 
However this folder doesn't seem to exist in the Ubuntu file structure.

I'm fairly new to servers and Ubuntu in general. Where should I be placing my files in order for them to show up when I visit my site?

Comment: have you installed apache2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your new `/var/www/` is the directory for apache2 so make sure you have it installed if you new to servers i'm going to assume you have not installed apache2 so you can follow this tutorial: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu

If you do have it installed check your apache2 settings `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you at least read the numerous guides available on google that detail setting up a web server on Ubuntu before continuing.

Comment: This is not an Answer it a comment and should be posted as such!